# Angular's constructor can't see the declared objects

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I got a strange Angular's (v9) behavior:

I have the following code:

```
public devices = [];

constructor(...){
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(p => this.devices = this.gotDevices(p));
  });
}//end of constructor

public gotDevices(deviceInfos){...}
```

Previously it worked now I get the error message saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'gotDevices' of undefined

Then I tried to modify the code in the following way:

```
public mydevices = [];

constructor(...){
let tempDevices = [];

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
     navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function (devices) {
     devices.forEach(function (device) {
         tempDevices.push(mydevice);
         this.mydevices.push(mydevice);
    }
    });
    });
    }).catch(function (err) {
    });
```

If I use this code then it can see the array tempDevices and it can use it but it still can't see this.mydevices and throws the same exception as above.

Why is that?

Comment: Try to move everything from the constructor into ngOnInit method.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and moved the code to the AfterViewInit() method.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has various Life-cycle hooks. NgOnInit is one of them.
Moving your code from the constructor to ngOnInit will solve the issue.

Angular bootstrap process has two mechanisms:
1) constructing components tree
2) change detection

Constructor of the component is called when Angular constructs components tree. All life-cycle hooks including ngOnInit are called as part of the following change detection phase. Usually a component initialization logic requires either some DI providers or available input bindings or rendered DOM. And these are available at different stages of Angular bootstrap process.

The constructor is called to initialize the class and not the component. The constructor is called before ngOnInit , at this point the component hasn't been created yet, only the component class has being instantiated thus your dependencies are brought in, but your initialization code will not run.

Thus, the constructor can be used to initialize the class members but should not have any logic.

```
public devices = [];

constructor(...){}

ngOnInit(){
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(p => this.devices = this.gotDevices(p));
  });
}

public gotDevices(deviceInfos){...}
```